# Packing data into arrays as fast as possible

Tags: c++

Im starting with an array of 100,000 bytes where only the lower 6 bits in each byte have useful data. I need to pack that data into an array of 75,000 bytes as fast as possible, preserving the order of the data.

```
unsigned int Joinbits(unsigned int in) {}
```

Comment: 6 bits * 4 = 24 bits = 3 bytes.  Write code to deal with four bytes at a time, doing 'the right thing' with each, and you're onto a winner.

Comment: What is your system word size? What is your system processor? "As fast as possible" is going to depend on system specific behavior, such as which operations result in the most parallelism and least amount of code.

Comment: Given that some of your 6-bit values will be overlapping byte boundaries in the result, endianness comes into play here. What endian do you want?

Comment: Does it really matter what the system specs are? A fast algorithm is a fast algorithm despite the processor speed.

Comment: To the extent that "a fast algorithm is a fast algorithm" is true, "the algorithm" is "take the bottom 6 bits of 4 adjacent bytes and stick them into the 24 bits of 3 other bytes". This is enough to tell us that the runtime is O(N), which is about the most unsurprising thing that could possibly ever be said in the field of computer science. Everything else is an implementation detail, and much will depend on the system. Endianness matters because the specification "pack that data, preserving the order" is actually *ambiguous about what the order should be*, however clear you might think it is.

Comment: Also: Why do you need to do this, and why does it need to be fast? 100,000 bytes is a **small** amount of data for today's computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// 00111111 00111111 00111111 00111111
//   000000   001111   111122   222222
void pack6(
  register unsigned char o, 
  register unsigned char const *i, 
  unsigned char const *end
) 
{
  while(i!=end)
  {
    *o++ =  *i          << 2u | *(i+1) >> 4u; ++i;
    *o++ = (*i & 0xfu)  << 4u | *(i+1) >> 2u; ++i;
    *o++ = (*i & 0xfcu) << 6u | *(i+1)      ; i+=2;
  }
}
```

Will fail if input length is not divisible by 4. Assumes high 2 bits of input are zero.
Completely portable. Reads 4 input bytes 6 times, so 50% inefficiency on reads, however the processor cache and compiler optimiser may help. Attempting to use a variable to save the read may be counter-productive, only an actual measurement can tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int pos=0; pos<100000; pos+=4)
{
   *(int*)out = (in[0] & 0x3F) | ((in[1] & 0x3F)<<6) | ((in[2] & 0x3F)<<12) | ((in[3] & 0x3F)<<18);
   in += 4;
   out += 3;
}
```

Comment: That works only on platforms where int may be with any alignment.

Comment: Will Segfault on most platforms due to misalignment.

Comment: Most platforms? Surely you mean some platforms. If you count Windows as a platform.

Comment: Also this idea only works on Little-Endian Platforms (like Intel).

Comment: I would argue that this works correctly on most platforms, because most platforms (for any practical definition of "most") are little-endian and allow misaligned ints. Furthermore, it would be the fastest way, because writing into 'out' through three separate 1-byte memory accesses would be slower.

Comment: You definition of most platforms is probably "intel". Wont work on PowerPc (big endian, won't tolerate misalignment). Won't work on any modern intel chip either because the alignment exception flag is usually set on. AFAIK won't work on AMD chips because they don't even have the flag in 64 bit mode.

Comment: See my solution: no point arguing, its too hard to predict low level performance, the only way is to actually measure it.

Comment: Nobody ever sets the alignment exception flag, it's a purely debugging feature (and a hard-to-access one at that). Intel in particular goes to great lengths to ensure that not only unaligned accesses do work, but they don't incur any performance penalty (if possible). As such, the code will work correctly on any x86/x64.

Answer (score 0):

This is C, I don't know C++. And is probably filled with bugs, and is by no means the fastest way, it probably isn't even fast. But I wanted to just have a go, because it seemed like a fun challenge to learn something, so please hit me with what I did wrong! :D

```
unsigned char unpacked[100000];
unsigned int packed[75000 / 4];

for (int i = 0; i < (100000 / 6); i += 6) {
    unsigned int fourBytes = unpacked[i];
    fourBytes += unpacked[i + 1] << 6;
    fourBytes += unpacked[i + 2] << 12;
    fourBytes += unpacked[i + 3] << 18;
    fourBytes += unpacked[i + 4] << 24;
    fourBytes += unpacked[i + 5] << 30;

    unsigned short twoBytes = unpacked[i + 5] >> 2;
    twoBytes += unpacked[i + 6] << 4
    twoBytes += unpacked[i + 7] << 10;

    packed[i] = fourBytes;
    packed[i + 4] = twoBytes;
}
```

Comment: For a start you should use unsigned chars and ints exclusively when doing bit manipulations on them. And your two final assignments won't work, they only assign bytes at position i and i+4.

Comment: Also you lose the last four bytes of unpacked[].

Comment: You want to pack 4 input bytes into 3 output bytes. You are currently packing 5 into 4, then trying to pack 3 into 2, where they don't fit. Also, assigning an int into a char array does not fill up 4 consecutive array slots with the int data (even assuming `sizeof(int) == 4` which is NOT guaranteed in C OR C++). It converts the int to a char and assigns it into the one specified slot.

Comment: @Yttrill thanks, I've updated it. Thanks everyone for helping me out learning! @tony can you explain what I did to lose the last four bytes?

Comment: @Karl-Knechtel Shouldn't the excess bits just be cut off? As in anything beyond 32 bits will just get lost, and the 2 bits should be lost by right shifting them. That way the 6 byte is split between the two packed ints.